# Rubymine: debugging using installed Puma-dev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine, puma

Is it possbile to have Rubymine connect to (and restart) an installed/running instance of Puma-dev for the debugging session?

I use Puma-dev to test my Rails app on "Appname".test, yet if I need to debug something in the app and want to use Rubymine's built-in debugger, I can only let it start an additional instance of Puma on Port 3000 (or whatever Port I choose) but not the already running Puma-dev on port 80/443.

Is it at all possible?

Comment: Have you tried `Attach to process...` yet? It can be found under the `Run` menu, or via the `Find action` dialog, and let's you connect a debugger session to a running Ruby process.

Comment: I hadn't. Unfortunately, it does not list the puma-dev-process. But thank you anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible with [remote debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/debugging-code.html#9c9bdbd4).  To configure, you have to make some changes to your app:

1. Add `export RUBY_DEBUG_PORT=1234` to `.env` or `.powenv` or any file puma-dev [will load an environment variable from](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev#configuration).  Feel free to use whatever port you'd like, although RubyMine uses 1234 by default.
2. Add the `ruby-debug-ide` and `debase` gems to your project's Gemfile.
3. Add an initializer to your project to initialize remote debugging, like so:

   ```
   if Rails.env.development? && ENV['RUBY_DEBUG_PORT']
     Debugger.start_server nil, ENV['RUBY_DEBUG_PORT'].to_i
   end
   ```
4. Restart puma-dev.
5. Go to Edit Configurations in RubyMine and add a "Ruby remote debug" config. Name it whatever you'd like. Change the port to the port you set via `RUBY_DEBUG_PORT`. Set your local and remote root folders to your project root.
6. Select your newly created configuration and click the Debug button.  It should connect to the debugger running in your puma-dev process.

Comment: This works beautifully! I was sure this should work but did not know how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you embellish the answer with the specific paths of the environment files to create and where to add the initializer in the project?

Comment: Works great with VS Code too!

Comment: This works but if you try to open up a console, it tries to spin up another debugger and fails since the port is already bound.